# how to show image in html

Tags: django, image

#models.py

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=False, blank=False, unique=False)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos/', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.name} {self.photo}'
```

#forms.py

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, label='Name')
    photo = forms.ImageField(required=False, label='Photo')
```

#views.py

```
def post(self, request:HttpRequest)->HttpResponse:
        # print(request.POST)
        form = ContactForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            Contact.objects.create(name=form.cleaned_data['name'], photo=form.cleaned_data['photo']).save()
#. . .
```

```
class ContactDetail(DetailView):
    model = Contact
```

#contact_detail.html

```
        <ol>
            <b>{{object.name}}</b><br>
            Photo: <img src="{{object.photo}}" width="55%">
        </ol>
```

I've this but when I want t see that contact, there's no image in page.
what I should do?

it just shows this [atajan(name)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Wmhc.png)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

In Django, when you're dealing with image fields in templates, you need to use the url attribute to get the URL of the image. Assuming {{ object.photo }} is an ImageField, you should update your template like this:

```html
<ol>
    <b>{{ object.name }}</b><br>
    Photo: <img src="{{ object.photo.url }}" width="55%">
</ol>
```